# Clarification on PayPal OAuth 2.0 Regarding Access/Refresh Tokens

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am working on putting an application together that uses PayPal's REST APIs, starting with the invoicing API.

I am used to getting an Access Token and a Refresh Token with other implementations of OAuth 2.0 (ie, Google, MS, etc), but it seems PayPal has done away with Refresh Tokens in this instance.

Could I get some clarification?  When the original access token expires, should I just request a new one?  Or should I be receiving a refresh token as well and refreshing the Access Token using that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Referenece: [Access token validity and expiration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/paypal-oauth2/#access-token-validity-and-expiration)

As the document mentioned, you should request a token and reuse it until it expires. Don't request a new token per session (and actually you will still get a same one before the one expires). It means that you should only request a new token when you meet a HTTP 401 response, and replace the old token with the new one.